# Looking for exact geocoordinates and/or zip code of location of nearest hub identified with "Distance to nearest hub"

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, proximity

I used the "Distance to nearest hub (line to hub)" tool from the QGIS processing toolbox to determine the distance between over 8.000 polygon centroids and a line layer. That worked perfectly. Now I want to know the exact geocoordinates of each of the identified nearest hubs, or, even better, the zip code of the area for each of the nearest hubs. My project already contains a layer with all the zip code polygons.
How do I do that the fastest way possible?

Here is what I did:
[image: Distance to nearest hub command as executed]

Comment: As in `join attributes by location` from the ZIP-code-layer to the hub-layer?

Comment: @Erik  created a new layer with the calculated distances. What I want for that layer is an additional column in the attributes table that shows me the zip code of where the nearest hub is located. Do you believe that can be achieved with "join attributes by location"? If so, could you maybe elaborate a bit on that.

Comment: So then you join attributes by location and then join attributes by nearest.